# Using ng-model-options updateOn:blur with uib-datepicker popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an input that allows a user to either type or select a date via the uib-datepicker calendar (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). When the user clicks on the input the datepicker pops-up allowing a user to make a selection Here is the input:

```
<input
     datepicker-append-to-body="calendarCtrl.appendToBody"
     uib-datepicker-popup="calendarCtrl.dateFormat"
     ng-model="calendarCtrl.ngModel"
     ng-click="calendarCtrl.open"/>
```

I need to allow the option for the user to not update the ng-model until the user has blurred the input. To do that I am trying to use ng-model-options.

```
 ng-model-options={updateOn: 'blur'}
```

This works great for when a user types a date into the input - the ngModel is not updated until a blur occurs and any validation isn't ran until blur. The problem is it breaks the functionality of the calendar popup in that nothing happens when a user then clicks on the open calendar to select a date. I'm assuming because when the user clicks on the calendar essentially a blur event is occurring on the input??

Has anyone came across this problem? Is there an ng-model-options option or something within the datepicker that would allow the user to still make a selection from the datepicker but not update the ng-model until a blur occurred on the input?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use a temporary property `ng-model="calendarCtrl.tempSelectedDate"` for ngModel in the Date Picker.

Then use the ngBlur event (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) to update the real property ie. set `calendarCtrl.ngModel = calendarCtrl.tempSelectedDate`.

Also, while nothing stops you using the scope property `calendarCtrl.ngModel` in `ngModel`, the code will be easier to read if you use more meaningful names like `ng-model="calendarCtrl.dateSelected"`.

Here's a working demo http://plnkr.co/edit/90mDPqzadjPt09Tp4SlI?p=preview.

I forked and expanded someone else's datepicker plnkr with two changes: adding `ng-blur="blurDate = startDate"` to the `<input>` & displaying the value with `Blur Date: {{ blurDate }}`.

Comment: I've added an example plnkr

Comment: In my case ng-blur is getting called every time I click in the input, because the calendar popping up is calling blur. In my blur function I am setting the ngModelController to $dirty which is then triggering validation of any errors. I ending up solving it by listening for a keydown on the input element and setting the input back to $pristine. And then when the user either clicks the calendar pop-up or blurs the input by clicking away, the form is set back to $dirty and looks for validation errors. Hacky solution but based on pre-existing code seems like the only option.